# Oracle CRM On-Demand - Use Tasks Status to update Service Request Status

Tags: oracle, crm, ondemand

We're using CRM On-Demand for our Service Group and I'm running into an application limitation and am wondering if anyone has a workaround or just some general ideas on how to accomplish our goal.

In the application, our major focus is around the Service Request and driving for users to create Tasks for all Activities related to working towards closure.  For example, a customer calls in and we need a technical resource to make a return call to diagnose the issue in detail, so a Task is assigned to that resource.  Once that Task has been marked as completed, I'd like the Status to be updated.  I tried creating a workflow using `JoinFieldValue()`, which wasn't working.  I tried a more basic approach and tried to just have a field on the Service Request be populated with the Status of the Task, but that did not work either.

Upon further investigation in the Help File, there is a relationship from the Activity object to the Service Request object, but not one the other way.

So, has anyone else run into this limitation and found some other method to have a Status change on the Task update the Status of a Service Request?

(Also, I'd like to try and avoid writing a custom web service for this purpose, which is why I'm trying to use the tools in the app)

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, if I well understood your issue is related on workflow cross object.
OCOD doesn't manage this type of workflow when you need to use workaround.

In order to cover a cross object worklflow you have many possibilities:

1. webservices as you said, but you could imagine a js code that will run WS and hosted directly into OCOD (in R19 you could hoste that in Client Side extension). That could be a good solution
2. Another one could be using Report with a custom look up functionnality with the usage of "Callback" function

I would prefer the 1st solution.

Comment: I'll send you an email.  Thanks for the response.